# Embedding the last video published on a Youtube channel

Tags: html, video, iframe, youtube, embed

I've been getting some mixed information while trying to embed an iframe that contains the most recently uploaded Youtube video of a certain channel.

I'm unsuccessfully trying to use the below format:

src="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANNEL_ID&orderby=published&maxResults=1"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you step by step directions:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en

Comment: Hi.Those directions apply only for a single video or a single playlist. I'm asking is there a way to embed the most recently uploaded video of a certain channel. (A channel may include many play lists).